# Can I use setter method for a replacement of final variable In the following way

Tags: java, java-8

Most of us understand the consequences of shared mutability, and it is said that always prefer immutability(final modifier, set once and you can't change it) if you have a chance. I have seen few coding examples where People are actually making fields final or setters as private or even removing setters for a class (which can be DTO, Model or Entity class) and another class (a builder class which can set values once to that immutable class) is used to create and set fields of the Immutable class  To ensure no other class is able to modify the state. Which seems a burden to me. SO I have come-up with this thought (below I am giving an example)

```
public class TestDataClass {

    private String name;
    
     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Supplier<String> supplier) throws Exception {
        if(Objects.isNull(name))
            {this.name = supplier.get();return;}
        throw new Exception("This field is immutable and already has a value "+this.name);
    }
}
```

In this way either you can set values through setter like this `objectOfTestDataClass.setName(() -> {return Perform_Desired_Logic;});`
or
`objectOfTestDataClass.setName(() ->"My Name");` if it is plain setter. Then also you dont have to create a bulder class or make setters private or omit setter method

In this way, I can get rid of variable initialization during Instantiation also once you set fields to become Immutable(I am not considering reflection).

I want your expert opinion to validate how legitimate is my thought, Can I consider this as Immutability? Am I missing something? in that case please correct me.

Comment: If object state can be mutated after creation, then it can't be considered as immutable.

Comment: I understood that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several things to note

1. Using a `Supplier<String>` instead of a `String` does not improve the code. There are only two cases, the intended case where the method is only executed once and the code of the supplier gets executed immediately and the erroneous case, where the supplier does not get executed, but where’s the sense in optimizing the erroneous case?
2. If a particular property supports being `null`, that approach fails to handle the case when it should be fixed to `null.
3. The API signature does not indicate that the class should be treated like immutable. Most readers will assume that it is mutable. So they may try to modify the object and not even notice the error if you’re going to remove the exception throwing statement, as said in a comment.
4. Immutable objects created by a builder are definitely completed and truly immutable once build. In contrast, your class allows the creator to forget setting some properties to fixed values, producing an actually mutable object.
5. Since instances of this class are not guaranteed to be immutable, they also do not have the guaranty to be thread safe that is usually associated with immutable objects.

Comment: last, his code is never success since it will always throws exception. :)

Comment: @Holger your answer is completely acceptable, thank you. one last question talking about thread safety what if I add synchronized in setter method is not that going to solve the thread safety problem?

Comment: No, making only the setter `synchronized` does not provide thread safety, if a thread is calling the getter concurrently to a setter invocation. You have to protect both, setter and getter, and then, you simply have a mutable object, with some restrictions. The whole point of thread safety through immutability is that a guaranteed absence of modifications implies an intrinsic safety that doesn’t require any synchronization.

Answer (score 10):

What you wrote allows to not set more than one time a field of an object.
But it is not a way to create object with a fully initialized state as a constructor or a builder can provide.
So, if the client manipulates the object with a **not complete** or **corrupted** state, it could not work as expected.

Besides, providing setters that may be invoked by the clients at compile time but **which the misuses would be known only at runtime (by throwing an exception) is not a friendly and good designed API**.

---

**Example of issue with an object that has a not complete state.**

Take a `Rectangle` class.
It is composed of 4 **mandatory** information (height, weight, x and y coordinates).
These are represented by 4 instance fields :

> int x, int y, int width, int height

Suppose the class provides an instance method `boolean contains(Point p)` to determinate if a `Point` (x, y coordinates) is included in it.

If you apply your method to value fields of this class, you may create  `Rectangle` instances with incomplete/partial state.
The `contains()` method could not work.
 It should perform different checks and if a field is missing in `Rectangle`, it should may be even throw an exception.

**Example of issue with an object which the state may be corrupted**

If your object may be manipulated by multiple threads, using your way to value the fields of the object may set the object in an unexpected and inconsistent state.
Two threads may manipulate the object at the same time and changing two fields that should not be changed in this way.
To avoid it, you are forced to use explicit synchronization mechanisms for both reading and writing of fields.

Ii you use a constructor or a builder, you have not these problems as you get out of the box a **complete**, **unmodifiable** (de facto  **thread-safe**)  object with a **clear API**.

Comment: I have added the exception just for checking during a test , Please avoid that part.

Comment: would you please explain what do you mean by "manipulates the object with a partial state".I don't get it.

Comment: @Mu Pi If you don't throw an exception, how will you indicate to the client of the method that the modification on the field was not occurred ?

Comment: *would you please explain what do you mean by "manipulates the object with a partial state"* - This means that the object can be used by other threads **before** your setter is called the first time. The fact that you *may* be avoiding it currently does not mean that this is valid forever.

Comment: @davidxxx instead of throwing an exception, I was thinking of adding a new state to the class which will hold the same information and invoker will have read access to that state.

Comment: @Mu Pi Adding a information to an instance, for example a state means modifying its state. So the instance is mutable. Besides, it makes the client code complex if they have to check the state changing. If you want to guarantee the immutability, in your `set...()` method, you should create a new object from the current object and apply the field modification on the new object and returns it. In this way, the current objects stays immutable.

Comment: @davidxxx Hii catching on what you said about the partial state (Thread Safety) as per my understanding if I add synchronized in the setter method, that is going to solve my problem is not it?

Comment: Partial state may create incomplete and not working object. It is not related to concurrent access but to the definition of the object . Inconsistent state is related to the concurrent access and using only synchronization on setters is not always enough as it may break the internal state of object (suppose for example you are using a `HashMap` that is not thread safe in the `set()` method ) and it may also violates rules of working of the object.  My initial answer were rather short. I updated with some details about these two points.